# regex for float python is not working

Tags: python, regex

I am using python 2.7. I am trying to write a regex which can match something like the following string:
_targetString = '[6152: 2152] * $ Total Time To Complete 1 Job: 4586.12 [Sec]'

The issue I am facing is that whenever the reported time as float my regex doesn't work. However, if I take the part of regex used to match the float and test it outside my original regex it works fine.

For example:
**Case 1**

```
_targetString = '[6152: 2152] * $ Total Time To Complete 1 Jobs: 4586.12 [Sec]'
_myRe = re.compile("\[\d+: \d\] \* \$ Total Time To Complete \d+ Jobs: \d+\.\d+ \[Sec\]")
_result = _myRe.match(targetString)
```

For this case the match doesn't work. I suspect that the issue is with *"\d+.\d+ [Sec]*" portion, as the regex worked for integers. The only thing I added to integer regex was *".\d+"* to handle floats.

**Case 2**

```
_targetString = " Jobs: 4586.12 [Sec]"
myRe = re.compile(' Jobs: \d+\.\d+ \[Sec\]')
_result = _myRe.match(targetString)
```

This works fine.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex expr:

```
_myRe = re.compile("\[\d+: \d+\] \* \$ Total Time To Complete \d+ Jobs: \d+\.\d+ \[Sec\]")
```

Comment: Thanks I was missing "+".

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `\d+.\d+` with something less restrictive like `\d+([.]\d*)?` "6152" won't match as "digits dot digits."